# Read file when updated. Error The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I'm want to read the last line of a CSV file when updated. When i save the updates the app brakes with this error **"The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process."** My question is, the "another process" is the watcher? If it's the watcher how can i read the file when updated?

```
public partial class Auto_Window : Form
    {

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        private int i = 0;

        public Auto_Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            watcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFolder"];
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFilter"];
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            var data = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);
            string last = data[data.Length - 1];

            if (i == 1)
            {
                tb_art1.Invoke(new Action(() => tb_art1.Text = last));
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                tb_art2.Invoke(new Action(() => tb_art2.Text = "ART2"));
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                tb_art3.Invoke(new Action(() => tb_art3.Text = "ARTO3"));
                MessageBox.Show("com?");
                tb_art1.Invoke(new Action(() => tb_art1.Text = ""));
                tb_art2.Invoke(new Action(() => tb_art2.Text = ""));
                tb_art3.Invoke(new Action(() => tb_art3.Text = ""));
                i = 0;
            }
       }

        private void btn_auto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btn_conf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0 && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0)
            {
                Config cfgform = new Config();
                cfgform.ShowDialog();
                watcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFolder"];
                watcher.Filter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFilter"];
            }
        }

        private void btn_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tb_art1.Text = "";
            tb_art2.Text = "";
            tb_art3.Text = "";
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Code updated

Comment: My guess is, your `OnChanged` handler is running multiple times per file.  So you're locking it yourself with the read.  Set a breakpoint on the first line and see if it gets hit multiple times per file.

Comment: is the code that's writing to the file also under your control? > then please show that, too. Is it an application like notepad? > then handle the locking and wait until the file will be available again. "watcher" do you mean a .NET `FileSystemWatcher`?

Comment: If it is another process under your control, you could have the other process use IPC instead of using file watching.  Send a message when there is an update to be processed.

Comment: @dlatikay that's very likely the case, yes.  The method signature in the question matches an event handler for the `FileSystemWatcher` class.

Comment: I updated the code on main post to the full code. The problem is on watcher blocking the csv after the uptade i think. I need to read the last line of the CSV when updated.

Comment: I tried to read the file with excel closed and it reads but when its open it breaks. I have any way to force read the file when excel is reading to?

Comment: Please read and respond to my first comment, @emnt.  The watcher does not lock files.

Comment: I didn't know where was the problem because i was on release instead of debug *facepalm*. I solver the problem and will leave here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem adding **watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;** at the start of the event and **watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;** at the end to prevent duplicated modifications ins seconds.

The other problem was the way i was reading the file. I solved in this way:

```
        var fs = new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var reader = new StreamReader(fs);

        await Task.Delay(500);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            searchList.Add(line);
        }
```